# WORDPRESS ERROR : Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php on line 406

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

Please Help!!

have error within my WP-Admin panel on my Menus page (wp-admin/nav-menus.php)

"Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/ewpfpaco/public_html/tow/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php on line 406"

my nav-menu.php on line 406 is as follows:

```
        // Insert Posts Page.
        $posts_page = 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ? (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) : 0;

        if ( ! empty( $posts_page ) ) {
            $posts_page_obj             = get_post( $posts_page );
            $posts_page_obj->posts_page = true;

            $important_pages[]   = $posts_page_obj;
            $suppress_page_ids[] = $posts_page_obj->ID;
        }
```

dont know where or how to resolve.

Comment: I have tried deactivating all plugins and it still shows.

Answer (score -1):

That warning tells you that your website's page_for_posts option is not defined while you have a menu item which tries to use that non-existing page.

Try to set Pages for posts in your setting->reading section.

URL: wp-admin/options-reading.php

You should define latest posts or posts page.

Or you just need to delete latest posts/news item from your nav menu.

Comment: Your awesome Elvin, thanks for the great advice.  you fixed it.